# Using grid area stacking blocks with same area label

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a 3 column sheet that put blocks in there specific column by their class.
Something like this:
[image]

I tried this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="type1">type1</div>
  <div class="type2">type2</div>
  <div class="type2">type2</div>
  <div class="type1">type1</div>
  <div class="type2">type2</div>
  <div class="type3">type3</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'type1 type2 type3';
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.type1{
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-area: type1;
}
.type2{
  background-color: forestgreen;
  grid-area: type2;
}
.type3{
  background-color: salmon;
  grid-area: type3;
}
```

but it will stack blocks with same `grid-area` on top of each other

[image]

Where is the problem in my code? and is it possible at all?
**p.s:** the blocks order is random, because I'm using a loop to iterate through my data and put the blocks on their columns base on their type.

Comment: Don't use grid areas. Specify grid auto flow as column and then tell the elements to use the dedicated column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shout out to Paulie_D!!

Here is what I've done base on his comment and everything is OK.

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}
.type1{
    background-color: aqua;
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
.type2{
    background-color: burlywood;
    grid-column-start: 2;
}
.type3{
    background-color: coral;
    grid-column-start: 3;
}
```